# Authentication token with "+"

Tags: ruby, query-string, jmeter

Does the authentication token generated in ruby for login transaction may contain "+" char ?

Because I want to execute the performance test on web page written in ruby I have written script and so on.. but always when this token contains this char "+" login transaction fails

thanks in advance for answer.

Answer:
Ok I should have mark 'encode' for this authentication token and after that everything is work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a query string, `+` [is interpreted as a space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding). You should encode your token with [`CGI.escape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/classes/CGI.html#M000093) or replace any `+` with `%2B`.